Java Spring Boot project. Cache filling with org.postgresql.core.Tuple
In a Spring project, up to 4 GB of memory fills up gradually over a few days or a week. I'm not sure which library is to blame for this object caching - Spring, Hibernate or JDBS or org.postgresql libriry directly. The only thing I see in VisualVM right now is almost two million org.postgresql.core.Tuple objects after i got a Heap space error.

Unfortunately, VisualVM does not show the owner of the list of Tuple objects.
To solve this problem, I first need to understand which library fills its cache with these objects and, most importantly, why these objects accumulate without being cleared.

Which library stores a list of Tuple objects?
If this is possible, how can I configure the cache of this library by limiting the number of stored Tuple objects?


1 no idea, 2 don't. You probably have a memory leak in your application, find the gc root of the arrays to determine which holds it.
